# Turn menu options on/off from Masterpage depending on user privs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to find a way to access a master page control in order to show/hide a menu option.

In my MP, I have:

```
   <div id="menucontainer">
        &nbsp;
            <ul id="menu">              
                <li id="menuHome"><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                <li id="menuNewHire"><%= Html.ActionLink("New Hire", "Index",     "newHire")%></li>
                <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Software", "Index", "Software")%></li>
                <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Hardware", "Index", "Hardware")%></li>
                <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Telecom", "Index", "Telecom")%></li>
                <li><%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%> </li>
```

Then a ContentPlaceHolder after that..What I want to do is in the controller, see if a user is in a certain AD group, if so, show or hide one of the menu options.  In this case, mnuNewHire I only want to be visible to certain users.

Any ideas on how to do this?  Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Geo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would externalize this menu into a separate controller and use [Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helper method. So for example you could have a model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public bool IsNoob { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class MenuController: Controller
{
    private readonly IUsersRepository _repository;
    public MenuController(IUsersRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        var userModel = new UserModel
        {
            // Maybe you could use the membership provider here
            // just don't know how you are handling authorization
            IsNoob = _repository.GetUserGroup(username) == "Noobs"
        }
        return View(userModel);
    }
}
```

and a corresponding partial view:

```
<ul id="menu">              
    <li id="menuHome"><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
    <% if (Model.IsNoob) { %>
        <li id="menuNewHire"><%= Html.ActionLink("New Hire", "Index", "newHire")%></li>
    <% } %>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Software", "Index", "Software")%></li>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Hardware", "Index", "Hardware")%></li>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Telecom", "Index", "Telecom")%></li>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%> </li>
</ul>
```

and finally in your master page:

```
<div id="menucontainer">
    <%= Html.Action("index", "menu") %>
</div>
```

Comment: Agreed, then that one can just provide a list of menu items to render.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  One question (BTW:  Very new to MVC so I hope this isn't to silly):  In the code for the controller, does this mean that code would need to be placed in each controller I have in order to prevent the menu item from being viewed if they are not a member of the group?  Meaning, I have a HardwareController, TelecomController, etc...so that code goes in each one?  Thanks again!

Comment: @George, no, that's a completely separate controller (`MenuController`) whose sole purpose is to manage and render the menu. So once you include it in your master page (using the `Html.Action` helper as shown in my answer) you no longer need to worry about it => it will be handled on all pages inheriting from this master.

Comment: I see.  So my partial view is called:  menu.ascx and then my controller is called menuController.  Right?  Once again, thanks for the help.

Comment: @George, the controller is called `MenuController` but the partial should be called `Index.ascx` because that's how I called the action inside, but you could use any name you like.

Comment: Darin, what is the:  IUsersRepository   I keep getting an error on that.

Comment: @George, it's normal, that's a custom repository that you will have to implement. This is your DAL layer which allows you to retrieve to which group a user belongs. Also see my comment about the membership provider.

Comment: Sorry.  In my Index.ascx, I get an error on the:<% if (Model.IsNoob).  Saying {Index.ascx(5): error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'IsNoob' and no extension method

Comment: @George, your view needs to be strongly typed to the `UserModel` class: `<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.UserModel>" %>`.

Comment: Awesome!  That did it.  Thanks so much for the help.  One of these days I'll figure out this MVC!  ;-)

Comment: @George, you are welcome and good luck with ASP.NET MVC, it's a great framework for building web applications :-)